# item of menu (html) loads javascript into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have javascript for load page from menu into div. This script loads only one page because there isn't defined for the others(var page = this.href;). I don't know how continue.. How I set to after click page2 script loads into div page2.html..I need to extend this script (I am beginner).  Thanks for answers.

[Here is JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rh5n1emp/11/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>
<ul>
<li ><a  class="active" href="page1.html" ><b>Page1</b></a></li>
<li ><a  href="page2.html" ><b>Page2</b></a>

</li>                                        
<li ><a   href="page3.html"><b>Page3</b></a>

</li>
<li ><a  href="page4.html"><b>Page4</b></a></li>
<li ><a  href="page5.html"><b>Page5</b></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>   
</div>

<div id="content"> </div>
```

CSS

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: rgb(1, 1, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 0px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
font-family: Times New Roman;
font-size: 70%;
}
nav ul:after {
content:"";
clear: both;
display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1;
}
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a.visited {
background: rgb(177, 2, 10);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 45px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
}
#menu {
position: relative;
width: 780px;
height: 35px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -388px;
overflow: hidden;
top: -20px;
}

#content {
position:       relative;
float: center;
width: 770px;
height: 670px;

clear:both;
margin:     0 auto;
border-radius: 7px;
overflow: hidden ;
top: 0px;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e){
    $('nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    e.preventDefault(); 

    var page = this.href;
    $.get( page, function( data ) {
      $( "#obsahtest" ).html( data );



    });


 });       
 });
```

Comment: Do you want to load external pages? Like this? `$('#content').load('page2.html');`

Comment: Yes, I do. Pages in menu (page2.html, page3.html and so on).

Comment: Then use this. `var page = $(this).attr("href"); $('#content').load(page);` Remove get function

Comment: This loads only one page (index.html), just like function get. How I set to after click page2 script loads page2.html?

Answer (score 1):

[check the js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/rh5n1emp/13/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var defaultpageurl =$('nav ul li a.active').attr('page-href');
     loadhtml(defaultpageurl);

     $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
       $('nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');        
        var pagelink = $(this).attr('page-href');
        loadhtml(pagelink);
      }); 

    function loadhtml(pageurl){    
    $("#content" ).load(pageurl);   //its nothing but the page url name
    }

});
```

changes on the html

```
<div id="menu">
 <nav>
 <ul>
    <li ><a  class="active" page-href="page1.html" ><b>Page1</b></a></li>
    <li ><a  href="#" page-href="page2.html" ><b>Page2</b></a>

    </li>                                        
    <li ><a   href="#" page-href="page3.html"><b>Page3</b></a>

    </li>
    <li ><a  href="#" page-href="page4.html"><b>Page4</b></a></li>
 <li ><a  href="#" page-href="page5.html"><b>Page5</b></a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>   
 </div>
```

just i re-modified in the code & changes in

**href="#" page-href="your page link"**

Comment: Thank you but this still doesnt work. Skript loads only 1 page ( index.html), for others .html loads nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is your html code.I just added the active class to all the  tag.

```
<div id="menu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="active" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp" ><b>Page1</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.csgnetwork.com/directselectdisable.html" class="active"><b>Page2</b></a></li>                                        
                            <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp" class="active"><b>Page3</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.csgnetwork.com/directselectdisable.html" class="active"><b>Page4</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.csgnetwork.com/directselectdisable.html" class="active"><b>Page5</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>   
            </div>

            <div id="content"> </div>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
anchorSelect=document.getElementsByClassName('active')

for(i=0;i<anchorSelect.length;i++){  
     anchorSelect[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     addToDiv(this.href);

   });

}

function addToDiv(x){
  console.log(x);
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object \
     type="text/html" data=' + x + ' width="100%" height=100%"></object>';
}
```